# Few words of Text to have linear gradient color - React native

Tags: reactjs, react-native, text, linear-gradients, maskedinput

I want to have some words of Text in linear gradient color. check [desired output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lvLXJ.png)

To achieve gradient text I am doing -

```
import React from 'react';
import {Text} from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view';

const GradientText = props => {
  return (
    <MaskedView maskElement={<Text {...props} />}>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={['red', 'green', 'blue']}
        start={{x: 0, y: 0}}
        end={{x: 1, y: 0}}>
        <Text {...props} style={[props.style, {opacity: 0}]} />
      </LinearGradient>
    </MaskedView>
  );
};

export default GradientText;
```

When wrapping inside  is not giving the required result -

```
<Text style={{color: 'white'}}>
    hello
    <GradientText>Gradient Text here</GradientText>
 </Text>
```

Flex is not helpful as multi-line sentence is not achievable using that.

Attached image of the desired output. Please help

Comment: What is the issue you're facing? What kind of result do you get? Are you getting any errors?

Comment: no errors, I basically want to make few words of paragraph as gradient and other to have white color. When I was wrapping the <GradientText> comp inside <Text> to work as span, the gradient text words were appearing in next line instead of same line.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Modify the `GradientText` component to accept children and apply the gradient to each character individually.

Here is working example:

```js
import React from 'react';
import { Text, TextProps, TextStyle, View } from 'react-native';
import LinearGradient from 'react-native-linear-gradient';
import MaskedView from '@react-native-masked-view/masked-view';

interface GradientTextProps extends TextProps {
  children: React.ReactNode;
  style?: TextStyle;
}

const GradientText = ({ children, style, ...rest }: GradientTextProps) => {
  const gradientColors = ['red', 'green', 'blue'];
  return (
    <MaskedView
      maskElement={
        <Text style={style} {...rest}>
          {children}
        </Text>
      }>
      <LinearGradient
        colors={gradientColors}
        start={{ x: 0, y: 0 }}
        end={{ x: 1, y: 0 }}>
        <Text style={[style, { opacity: 0 }]} {...rest}>
          {children}
        </Text>
      </LinearGradient>
    </MaskedView>
  );
};

export default function App() {
  return (
    <View style={{ flex: 1, justifyContent: 'center', alignItems: 'center' }}>
      <GradientText style={{ fontSize: 40 }}>{`Hello World
      Hello World
      Hello World
      `}</GradientText>
    </View>
  );
}
```

Comment: Thanks Fotios, I made some modifications to your solution according to the usecase and was able to achieve it. Cheers!

Comment: this gradient text approch is not working in android

Comment: @SakshiSrivastava Srivastava Check the Android-specific setup for the packages...

Comment: basically, { opacity: 0 } is not getting applied on <Text> that's why gradient is not visible on android

Comment: @SakshiSrivastava try setting the color of the text to 'transparent'

Comment: didn't work out. the text became invisible.